# Error: Econn is refused in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm going through a RabbitMQ tutorial in node.js

Every time I run `node send.js` I keep getting an error saying the econn is refused.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
var when = require('when');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn){
        return when (conn.createChannel().then(function(ch){
                var q = 'hello';
                var msg= 'Hello World!';

                var ok = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

                return ok.then(function(_qok){
                        ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
                        console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'",msg);
                        return ch.close();
                });
        })).ensure(function() {conn.close(); });;
}).then(null,console.warn);
```

Here's what the error says:

```
  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what I need (I'm not too experienced with node.js). But I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the localhost server. I tried googling and searching on here at stackoverflow, but nothing that I could find to my use.

Comment: Have you started the RabbitMQ server before starting your application?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo no I haven't. What is the command to start it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start RabbitMQ-server before connecting. If you installed RabbitMQ as a system package in Linux, issue:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

If you downloaded and unpacked it somewhere (any OS), then launch the `rabbitmq-server` script you will found in the `sbin/` subdirectory.

If you did not download the server, then get the appropriate package from [RabbitMQ download page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html).

Comment: I tried that command on Mac. It said service:command not found

Comment: I did a homebrew install of rabbitmq

Comment: `service` is used on most Linux distribution, not Mac. Add `sbin` to your path with `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin` then launch server with `rabbitmq-server`.

Comment: I'm not understanding by what you mean adding sbin to my path. Is there a file that I need to overwrite? If so, which one.

Comment: Well, just issue `/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server` and you are set :)

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. But when the server is running, how can I run 'node send.js' ? It seems like I must abort the server to run that node command

Comment: You should use 2 terminal windows, one for the RabbitMQ server and another for Node.JS

Comment: lol sometimes I wonder why I ask some questions; the effects of thinking too hard. Thanks that worked.